# Trying to load a .tsv file from the front end. The file stays on my server. How do I do this using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, d3.js

I have an function like this on my Express server, which is sending a file that depends on D3.JS.

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
   var timestamp = utility.timestamp();
   console.log('[' + timestamp + '] Request made to render dashboard.')
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/front_end/index.html')
});
```

This appears to be working correctly.

Once the file is served, it needs a data file in order to render properly. I attempt to access it as follows.

```
d3.tsv("../data/data.tsv", function(error, data) { // DO STUFF HERE }
```

Anyway, needless to say, because the file that is being sought is actually on the backend, I'm not able to access it this way from the code I have served the user.

I have also tried hitting an endpoint that sends the .tsv file. However, there is an error that has to do with cross domain requests.

```
d3.tsv("localhost:3000/userAccessData", function(error, data) { // DO SAME STUFF }
```

Does anyone know an effective way to send either both files using Express or access the file on the server using a request?

Comment: It sounds like you would need to change the served Javascript file and embed the data.

Answer (score 0):

I initially fixed this problem by placing the resource file in a folder labeled as public. :D

Later, I found out that the browser actually caches the resource on the front-end and does not re-request it each time. To circumvent that and ensure up to date data is available, I added sockets.io to my project as well.